# Swift 3 : Stomp WebSocket library

Tags: websocket, stomp

I want to subscribe to a topic after successful connection, however I am not able to do so. I have tried all the libraries for eg.Starscream(only for WebSocket connection), StompClient, ActionCableClient, FayeSwift etc. but none seem to work. I want to connect and subscribe to Stomp Client WebSocket, Please suggest me some WebSocket library that can connect and subscribe to STOMP Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not work successfully with other libraries. That's why I've created StompClient library. I hope that helps.

**Cocoapods:**
https://cocoapods.org/pods/StompClientLib

**Github:**
https://github.com/wrathchaos/StompClientLib

Comment: Hello Kuray..!! Your library is really very easy to understand and good. I have tried so many libraries but still I am not able to subscribe. I really don't know why? All my attempts have failed. socketClient.subscribe(destination: "topic/live"), this method returns nil body, no json response. I don't know what's the problem. Do I have to pass something extra to subscription, Is there problem in library or Is there a fault at server side/client side..??  I am really blank. Please help.. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: @Bella hello, I've tested my library and using it right now. Can you please test your websocket or stomp protocol? Are you sure that your topic is working ? Also, could you connect the websocket ?

Comment: Hello Kuray! Yes it is getting connected. There is problem in subscription. Can you please commit sample app, so that I can refer to it. I have done as you had written in USAGE.

Comment: @Bella i will add the sample today, please check your topic string and check your "/" in your topic.

Comment: my topic is /topic/live.  I am passing it as  socketClient.subscribe(destination: "/topic/live")

Comment: @Bella I've added the Example. Please check it out. Also, I've tested it. Please try "topic/live/". If still not working, I can help you via teamviewer or something like that.

Comment: My json response after I subscribe to the topic is in this form [Dictionary<String, Any>].   How to get json response after successful subscription??   I am not able to understand whether the subscription is done successfully or not??   Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Bella Can you please share an example of full response ? I mean not from application, from server.

Comment: I am getting body: nil, after I debugged sendFrames(). What can be the reason.

Comment: @Bella I think your stomp sends nil body. Did you check the backend?

Comment: Hey Kuray..!! thanks. It Worked...  but while installing pods for ios version 8.0 I get this error.... [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `StompClientLib` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `StompClientLib` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.   It gets installed only for version 10.0 . As a developer I have to use minimum version 8.0... So that it is compatible with all devices.

Comment: @Bella I'm glad to hear that it works ! I'm going to check minimum version immediately ! :)

Comment: @Bella I've updated the pod and library. Can you please check the minimum version ? If you still get the same version problem, let's wait up a bit to cocoapods' server get the update. Sometimes updating a pod take a bit longer. Again, I'm very happy to hear that it works for you :) Happy coding!

Comment: Hi...! I tried with version 8.0, but it's not working. It still requires higher version 10.0. I just hope I don't get any errors in future in AppDelegate for NSPersistentContainer class... Right now I am running my project by doing @available(iOS 10.0, *) in AppDelegate... Thanks a lot for helping..! :-)

Comment: @Bella I've fixed the minimum version problem. I'm going to change the SocketRocket library which I use it for websocket connection from Facebook. I'm going to make it full Swift library :) I've checked and it is working on iOS 8 right now, please execute "pod update" before you try!

Comment: JSON Body : Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x60800027b440>({
    "id": 1,
    "places": [
      {
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "name": "Pune"
      },
      {
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "name": "Mumbai"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "places": [
      {
        "state": "Punjab",
        "name": "Amritsar"
      },
      {
        "state": "Punjab",
        "name": "Pathankot"
      }
    ]
  }
)
) how to pass this to an Array of type [Dictionary<String,Any>]. I am passing this Array to tableView delegate methods. Please help

Comment: @Bella Here is your solution :) https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-32-how-to-convert-json-anyobject-to-custom-model-c07752e02b9e

Do not forget that you need to handle your object/array depends on what you need :) 
Have fun!

Comment: Hi.. This code is great... I have done this handling in                 func stompClient( )............ I have used tableView to show the name of places. in numberOfRowsInSection I am getting array.count as nil. I have done array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! [Dictionary<String,Any>]..... I know I haven't called any func in ViewDidLoad, but since all data comes in delegate method, how am I supposed to solve this problem. Kindly help..!

Comment: @Bella please check decoded.count, it should be the same as your json array's size.

Comment: Count is correct. but how I am supposed to use it in numberOfRowsInSection(). I want to show number of rows in tableView, for that I need to append decodeJson to array of type [Dictionary<String,Any>].And then use array.count in numberOfRowsInSection()

Comment: @Bella why don't you create a public dictionary variable and put decode's data to that dictionary? Then you can use json dictionary wherever you are

Comment: I did that @Kuray.... but numberOfRowsInSection() is still nil.... it is the first delgate method that gets called. And all the handling I have done in func stompClient(client: StompClientLib!, didReceiveMessageWithJSONBody jsonBody: AnyObject?, withHeader header: [String : String]?, withDestination destination: String) {} this func. So row count will be 0

Comment: Did you call tableView.reloadData() ?

Comment: @Bella what was the problem?

Comment: Instead of appending, I assigned the value of decoded json to array. And called tableView.reloadData() in func stompClient(){}. It is working.

Comment: Hey Kuray.. Now I have to show a signal that indicates whether a socket is connected or disconnected. It should show red, if client is not connected to websocket and green if connected. I have to indicate this at the top of screen, which has a dot-like UI signal. Please help..!!

Comment: @Bella I'v added .isConnected method to check that socket is connected or not. You can use it :)

Comment: In which method to check it but?.. In ViewDidLoad() after calling  openSocketWithURLRequest() I did if socketClient.isConnected(){
            ConnectionIndicator.image = UIImage(named: "device-connected")
        }else{
            ConnectionIndicator.image = UIImage(named: "device-disconnected")
        }..... It didn't work.. :-(

Comment: You should call it inside of : stompClientDidConnect delegate. After your subscription, you can check that your connection's status :)

Comment: I did that. but the colour does not change. As soon as phone is connected to webSocket the colour should change.

Comment: I need to see the code but you should check the connection in stompClientDidConnect part.

Comment: When there is no internet connection, There is error Could not cast value of type '__NSCFError' (0x1042ff608) to 'NSString' (0x1034e5c40). in StompClientLib.swift line delegate.serverDidSendError(). I don't want this error. Instead it should show could not connect to internet.. Please solve this issue...!

Comment: The connection was proper, but while testing when I disconnected and run the app again, I got the above error

Comment: You should handle the internet connection error on your application part. You might check the internet connection before every websocket or request connection.

Comment: What condition should I use to check the internet or socket connection?? Is socket?.readyState == .OPEN correct?? in func stompClientDidConnect(client: StompClientLib!)...Please help.I am doing it for first time

Comment: You need to handle the internet connection by writing another method or class. The library itself does not have an ability to handle internet connection. However, I'm going to make a library for internet connection soon :)

Comment: @KurayÖğün - Could you please help me here - https://github.com/WrathChaos/StompClientLib/issues/14

Comment: @Krunal Hey, I've answered you, please give me a feedback :)

Comment: @KurayÖğün - Thank your for response. I described there, what exact issue I've been facing. Can you please let me know what's wrong over there. Here I raised my query on SO - [StompClientLib - unsubscribe socketclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472473/stompclientlib-unsubscribe-socketclient)

Comment: Hi @FreakyCoder, Thanks for sharing such a valuable library with us and thanks for your contribution. I am using your library and successfully getting the data from the server.
But, my requirement is that whenever the server got disconnected, the app should try to reconnect until the socket is not successfully reconnected. I am calling socketclient.reconnect() method on stompClientDidDisconnect method. But it is not working. Can you help me for the same?

Comment: Hello @ErRahulRajkumarGupta, Thank you so much for these kind words :) 
Can you please open an issue on the Github so everyone can help or find some solutions. Can you please tell me which Swift, XCode and iOS version are you using?